# WSO2 EI, While loop with Proxy Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to ***loop*** through Response(*jsonarray*) from Data service to call **another service** using previous each response field (for example userID)

So i manipulate these 2 service's response into Main response to return to client, it will be JsonArray

*Please refer below questions :*

1. **Is it possible to create ArrayList and put some property(mediator) data in Loop?**
2. **How to implement properly while loop (iterator or foreach mediator)?**

`Note : Basically, i am trying to use service orchestration But Loop is required, i need each services response and fields to be mixed for response`

*How to do that ?*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Iterate mediator and the Aggregate mediator in WSO2 EI. Both support jsonpath expressions hence you can manipulate and read the responses as you want. Please refer to the below blog for an example.

https://medium.com/@arunans23/iterate-over-json-payload-with-wso2-enterprise-integrator-8ccb9cdd2c70

When implementing your feature if you get more specific issues please post them here.